# ServletContextListener will be not invoked

Tags: java, tomcat7

Actually it is a traditional problem, but all solutions i have found do not work, but i guess it must be a stupid solution: So i have a dynamic web project, which includes a ContextListener that overrides the two methods contextInitialized and contextDestroyed and is annotated with @WebListener.

My pom.xml looks like:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>mytestproject</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>mytestproject Maven Webapp</name>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>mytestproject</finalName>
 <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My class ContextListener.java looks like:

```
package de.mygroup.mypackage;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("The application started");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("The application stopped");
    }
}
```

and my web.xml looks like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

I can create the jar-file and start it. When i call localhost:8080 and i can see just an empty white page and furthermore i do not see the output defined in the ContextListenerClass at the command promt. Is there anything that i forget? It seems that he annotation @WebListener does not work.

Thanks in advance
DD

Comment: ok, found my mistake: Tomcat expects a war file. I corrected the line to: <packaging>war</packaging>